# Call grep in a way that finds all lines without a specific string?

Tags: perl

I am trying to build a Perl program in which uses `grep` to find specific strings and to avoid others.

The solution for finding the relevant strings is easy:

```
open(FILE, "<".$file) or next;
my @listOfLines = <FILE>;
close FILE;

my $strToGrep = "strToFind1|strToFind2";

my @results   = grep /$strToGrep/, @listOfLines;
```

But how do I avoid finding no relevant strings?

I want to avoid:

```
my @subStrToAvoid = qw/ strToAvoid1 strToAvoid2 strToAvoid3 /;
```

Is there a way you can use Perl's `grep` in the same way as the 
`grep` utility with certain flags from bash?

Comment: You want to include something, and exclude others?

Comment: You have three requirements here: 1) *"find all lines without a specific string"*  2) *"avoid finding no relevant strings?"* 3) Avoid `my @subStrToAvoid = qw/ strToAvoid1 strToAvoid2 strToAvoid3 /`    Those are incompatible. Why do you want to avoid finding no strings, and why do you want to avoid that array assignment?

Comment: @Sobrique - yes. 
Borodin - Let me explain again. I want to the answer to include specific strings (strToFind1 or strToFind2) and exclude others (strToAvoid1, strToAvoid2 and strToAvoid3)

Answer (score 4):

Easily - perl's `grep` function isn't a simple regex grep, it can do all sorts of magic on the default. You can take pretty much any code block that returns a true/false result, and 'feed' it with `$_`. `regex` by default will act on `$_` so you can have multiple regex conditionals quite easily.

So you can:

```
#turn your 'avoid' list into a regex
my $avoid = join ( "|", map { quotemeta } @subStrToAvoid );
#note - quotemeta is here in case @subStrToAvoid includes 
#regex meta characters like "|" or "."
   $avoid = qr/($avoid)/;
#match your regex but exclude the avoid regex
my @results = grep { m/$strToGrep/ and not m/$avoid/ } @listOfLines;
```

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Perhaps you should describe the question that you're answering?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to grep is a condition, which can be negated like any other condition with `!`:

```perl
my $ignore = join "|", qw/ strToAvoid1 strToAvoid2 strToAvoid3 /;
my @result = grep !/$ignore/, @listOfLines;
```

You can chain the greps if needed:

```
my @out = grep /$ok/, grep !/$notOk/, @list;
```